# Как хранить объекты в приложении?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Всем привет!
Собственно, вопрос в теме. 
Допустим я загружаю новости JSON'ом с сервера. Мне бы сохранить их в какой-то объект Article, чтобы к ним можно было обратиться из разных частей приложения.

Как хотелось бы:

Вытягиваю с сервера новости -> сохраняю их локально в объекты -> нажимаю на конкретную новость, открывается новая View, в которую я передал номер новости -> подгрузил из обекта Article с переданным номером все данные

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно хранить не объекты, а данные. И на основе данных создавать объекты.
Локально хранить данные можно с помощью: `CoreData`, `UserDefaults`, `JSON file`.

Если, конечно, вы хотите сохранять именно объекты, то вам необходимо реализовать `Codable` `Protocol` для того, чтобы, к примеру, сохранить объект в `UserDefaults`.